# How to change add javascript files dynamically in the header of an html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page, I need to add some reference to JS files in the head of the html.
The following code is working, but the scriptTVKeyValue is always being added before the tag 
I would like to add instead directly after 
Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
<head>
        // I want reference added here
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
        // Reference to file added here
</head>
```

```
// APP_MAIN.onLoad()
            var scriptTVKeyValue = document.createElement('script');
            scriptTVKeyValue.type = 'text/javascript';
            scriptTVKeyValue.src = '$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js';
            head.appendChild(scriptTVKeyValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://www.jspatterns.com/the-ridiculous-case-of-adding-a-script-element/

You should have the answer

Answer (score 1):

Solution using **jQuery**:

```
//Take the refference to the previous node
var $jsFile = $container.find('[src="js/jquery.js"]'); 
var fileName= '$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js';

// Insert the script
$jsFile .insertAfter($('<script>')
  .attr('type', 'text/javascript')
  .attr('src', fileName));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy/allowed to use a JS library, then you can load the scripts with [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) It has advanced features to do this: it will enable you to call functions after your dynamically added script is loaded.